# How can I create an array of objects in a form and then send this array to the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I create multiple `Step` objects in a form and when I click the "Create" button these are sent to the controller's POST method?

I don't know what I use to display the array of Step objects that I create in terms of a `@Html` helper, I suppose, to then eventually be sent to the controller on "Create".

Additionally, I will need to think about editing and deleting a Step as depicted by the image below.

[image: Image of the form to add Steps for a recipe]

The **Recipe Model**

```
    public class Recipe
    {
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }

        [RequiredIfButtonClicked("CreateRecipe")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Title cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Title:")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$", ErrorMessage = "Must start with a capital letter, only alphabetic characters and no spaces allowed.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Used to create a single Step for a Recipe
        public Step Step { get; set; }

        // A Recipe has many steps
        public Step[] Steps { get; set; }
    }
```

The **Step Model**

```
    public class Step
    {
        public int StepId { get; set; }

        [RequiredIfButtonClicked("CreateRecipe", ErrorMessage = "At least one step is required.")]
        [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Instructions cannot be longer than 500 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Step Instructions:")]
        public string Instruction { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: When user clicks on `Add Step` button, the content inside the textarea will be collected. Then, the textarea will be cleaned. And when user clicks on `Create` button, all of data will be sent to the controller. Right?

Comment: Have the user input a string with data separated by a comma, and in the controller that accepts this string, use `.Split(",")` and this will save the values into an array.

Comment: @Tân Yup, but currently I only know how to send one Step to the controller, the data inside the textarea. I don't know how to store each Step into an array (upon clicking "Add Step") and then send the array (with all the steps) to the controller.

Comment: Re *"...what I use to display..."*: Do you mean *"...what I* ***can*** *use to display..."* (more like question)? Please respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64797576/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I suggest to use jQuery to send an Ajax request to controller with [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

I imagine that you've already defined some event for `Add Step` button to collect data using JavaScript.

And the data looks like:

```js
var steps = ['step_1', 'step_2'];
```

In your model, because `Step` class requires `Instruction` property, you can make a loop with that array to create a new model:

```js
var model = {};
model.Steps = [];

for (var step of steps) {
  model.Steps.push({ Instruction: step });
}
```

You can also use this model to add more properties like `Name` or `Step` object:

```js
model.Name = $('.Title').val();
model.Step = {
  Instruction: steps[0]
};
```

Then, compress data to `FormData` before sending:

```js
var data = new FormData();
data.append('Name', model.Name);
data.append('Step', model.Step);
data.append('Steps', model.Steps);

$.ajax({
  url: '/your_controller',
  type: 'your_request_type',
  data: data
}).done(function (response) {
  console.log('Responsed data from server:', response);
}).fail(function (error) {
  // If there is some error: path not found or invalid request format...
  // the error can be logged here
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Just out of interest, is it possible to Post Ajax like in the solution along with posting model properties without Ajax (with @Html helpers)? If I use Ajax then the fields using Html.EditorFor are null in the controller.

Comment: @James Yes. If you want to design a small form, such as: some text input(s), some textarea(s)..., you don't really need ajax. But for future, ajax could be very helpful if you want to send some file(s) to controller, or manage the request status (success, error...). Also, ajax doesn't require to refresh the page, that means you can hit controller multiple times without reloading page.